# Express js repeat route journey with context

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been sitting with this for few days already and I'm brain dead from this and can't figure the best way to approach this.

What I would like to achieve is to be able to repeat the route journey with new context data on the start. So for rxample:

```
app.get('/test', testGet);
app.post('/test', testPost);
```

having those two routes I would like:

1. GO through testGet handler (fetch necessary data and present ui for Form)
2. Gather Form data and submit it for the testPost handler
3. Process data from form on testPost and generate appropirate new payload
4. Redirect again to the testGet handler with new payload data from testPost if journey not successful

How I would pass that new data to the testGet on redirection? Can't figure the best way.
Redirect doesn't accept any payload. Redirecting with query params is kinda way to go but it appends the url string with query string to the user which I would like not to be present to the user. And that data would not be a simple string but an object containing few arrays and properties

Comment: Can you post code ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this

```
const handleRequest = (req, res, next) => {
    const view = 'myView.jsx';
    let myData = {};

    ...do the common job

    if (req.method === 'GET') {
         return res.render(view, data)
    }

    /* here you are in the post method */
    data = /* modify your data with the req.body */

    return res.render(view, data)
};


app.get('/test', handleRequest);
app.post('/test', handleRequest);
```